# Open PDF file in a new window in the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an icon that when clicked calls a controller and it converts the array into bytes in PDF and this opens the document in the same window.

I need the document to open a new windows in the browser in the same tab.

Icon that calls controller using URL action.

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <a href="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home" , new { item.Id })"> <i class="fas fa-eye"> </i></a>
</div>
```

Controller that converts bytes to PDF.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPDF(Guid id)
{
    var vm = new ViewModels.Home.AttachmentViewModel();
    var result = vm.GetServiceAttachment(id));

    //Function to get the file information from DB .
    
    byte[] file;
    foreach (var attachment in result)
    {
        file = attachment.File;
        byte[] byteArray = file;
        return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/pdf");
    }
    return null;
}
```